# ASE Sybase Module for PHP7

Tags: php, sap-ase

Does anyone know if there is a PHP module for Sybase Active Server Edition (ASE), compatible with version 12.5 that will work with PHP 7+ since the removal of sybase_connect I'm struggling to find a driver and according to the documentation slqsrv needs MSSQL 2005+

I do have freeTDS installed, and have looked at PDO_DBLIB but it seems that it's not really coming recommended.

I'm running on Ubuntu Server LTS.

Plan B is it worth just trying to migrate my Script to something like Python -
 please not Perl it screws with my head ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe ASE OpenClient SDK contains drivers for Perl, PHP and Python.You can get this either by downloading the full SDK from the SAP support website, but it may be easier to just download the ASE Express Edition from https://www.sap.com/community/topic/ase.html.
The connectivity drivers are located in $SYBASE/OCS_16-0.